# InputMismatchException Error Data Types

Tags: java

I'm playing around with Java for the first time and an error is appearing.  I don't understand why.

The error is:

> java.util.InputMismatchException

It says that the problem is in line 20 `("price = in.nextDouble();")`, but I can't understand the problem.

It looks like that the problem happens after I insert the number of days, the cost per day and I used decimal, I put for example `34.98`. Isn't the point of using double to be able to use decimal numbers?

Here is the code:

```
int days;
        double price;

        System.out.println("How many days you will be here?");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        days = in.nextInt();

       System.out.println("How much you can afoord per day?");
       price = in.nextDouble();

        double total = price * days;
        System.out.println("Youll be paying "+ total);
```

Comment: What culture are you in? Perhaps it was expecting `,` as the decimal separator. (Note that for currency values, you should probably use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int days;
    double price;

    System.out.println("How many days you will be here?");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    days = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How much you can afoord per day?");
    price = in.nextDouble();

    double total = price * days;
    System.out.println("Youll be paying "+ total);

  }
}
```

Output

```
Executing Build Command: javac /root/HelloWorld.java                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
How many days you will be here?                                                                                                                                                               
3                                                                                                                                                                                             
How much you can afoord per day?                                                                                                                                                              
34.98                                                                                                                                                                                          
Youll be paying 104.94                                                                                                                                                                          
Process exited successfully
```

Comment: Strange, for me didnt worked, are you using eclipse? im using IntellyJ

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem, i had to add after Scanner... "in.useLocale(Locale.US);"
That is why it got this error.